# Launching the google maps app from within my app

Tags: android, maps

I've been searching around the internet, the android dev guide and stackoverflow for almost 2 hours now and can't seem to find the answer that I'm looking for so I'm just going to go ahead and ask.

I'm building an app that has a button called "Find it nearby" that's only purpose is when the user clicks on it, it will call over to the Google maps app using some perimeters that I will set in place. I do not want to just use a mapview from within my app, I want to launch and use the full google maps app itself.

Now to be very specific, I have all the permissions needed and the maps url inside of my manifest. I have all of my application code set in place (buttons, xml, classes etc) and they are all ready and usable other then the code that will launch the Google maps app and once again, I have looked on here, google searching, various books, and the android dev guide to no avail.

I just need to know what the code is that I need to put into my app that will enable it to launch the actual, full google maps app from within my app and NOT a mapview. Any assistance would be greatly welcomed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String uri = "geo:"+ latitude + "," + longitude;
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

At Android SDK documentation, you can see the below options you can try in the above uri string value.

[image]

For more info refer this: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I am still unsure of where to place this piece of code at. I have an xml file that has <com.google.android.maps.MapView and all of that in it, I have the permissions in the manifest, and I have a .java file for the maps activity but it's empty at the moment as I am unsure of where/how to insert this code to enable it to work properly. If you can give me some further insight that would be great.

Comment: I am sure you are newbie in android, but still you can implement this code inside button click listener or at any event.

Comment: Yes, I am still new to creating android apps. I want to thank you very much for helping me out on this and I'm glad to know that there's help from other members in the community if I need it.

Comment: @fuzz ok fine, not an issue but as i had mentioned earlier that you need to write the above code in any click listener or any event.

Comment: @PareshMayani Thank you for the snip, it was helpful, can we add Zoom level with ActionView Intents??

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code

```
String url = "geo:0,0?q=Coffee Shop";
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

This will use the original google Map Application for current location and if you want to search for a particular place then use url as `"geo:0,0?q=Coffee Shop Near LocationName"`.